# Как правильно сделать трансформацию обьектов из бесконечного потока?

Tags: java, android, rxjava

Получаю из бд данные `Flowable` но когда конвертирую их так

```
return getGoodsRepository()
                .getAllItems()
                .flatMapIterable(itemList ->itemList)
                .flatMap(item ->Flowable.just(getGoodsModelMapper().transformTo(item)))
                 .toList()
                .toFlowable();
```

то данные не поступают , я предпологаю это из за того что я делаю `toList`

но как обойти это ???ведь без `toList` я не смогу сделать масси обьектов из `flatmapa`

Comment: напишите какие данные получаете  в метод и что вы хотите вернуть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас не происходит эмита `onComplete` события, т.к. цепочка начинается с `Flowable`, а он сам это событие не кинет. В итоге оператор `.toList()` никогда не выполнится, т.к. он сохраняет к себе всё что к нему пришло и не отдаёт пока не получит событие `onComplete`.

Вам надо усложнить цепоку так:

```
getGoodsRepository()
    .getAllItems()
    .flatMapSingle( items ->
        Flowable
                .fromIterable(items)
                .flatMap( item ->
                    Flowable.just(getGoodsModelMapper().transformTo(item)))
                )
                .toList()
    )
```

Это сработает, т.к. `Flowable.fromIterable(items)` вызовет `onComplete` после эмита всех элементов, `toList()` сработает и цепочка пойдёт дальше.

Comment: вот это геморой , я пошел другим путем убрал    .toList()
                .toFlowable(); а после flatmap делаю buffer(1)

Comment: @elik, так не пробовал, но да, вариантов решения несколько, вроде)